# Can I use a logitech C170 webcam on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, webcam, microphone, logitech

Does it need additional drivers? My computer does have a microphone, so I can always use that one. I just want to be sure before I buy it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. From [Linux Hardware Guide.com](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2012-10-07-logitech-c170-webcam):

> The Logitech webcam C170 has the USB ID 046d:082b and is automatically
>   recognized and initialized by Ubuntu since version 11.04.
>
> The integrated microphone is supported by Linux [...]
>
> The push button located at the webcam to make snapshots is supported by Xorg [...].