# Can I use C170 Logitech Webcam in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, webcam, logitech

Please help me to know how to install C170 Logitech Webcam in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

The good news is that this device should be automatically recognised and setup by Ubuntu. It has [the tick of approval](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2012-10-07-logitech-c170-webcam) and demonstrated full working order with Linux from the Linux Hardware Guide. So to 'install' simply plug it in and you should be right to go.

Once you have physically plugged the device in and it has been recognised by Ubuntu you can test it out with `cheese` or `guvcview`. Install these as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese guvcview
```

Cheese will automatically detect your webcam and display live video stream and from there you can take photographs or record live streams. Other possible applications under Ubuntu that can utilise your webcam are vlc, MPlayer and Skype. Have a look at the Ubuntu Community Docs link in my 'References' for a bit of a steer into getting these ones running.

**References:**

- [Can I use a logitech C170 webcam on Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346543/can-i-use-a-logitech-c170-webcam-on-ubuntu-13-04)
- [Ubuntu Community Docs: Webcam](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)

Comment: For me (on 16.04), the webcam did not work without `guvcview` installed but worked after I installed the package.

Comment: It's broken with both 16.04 and 14.04 now, with both guvcview and cheese. There is [a launchpad bug about it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1295247). Ok, though it works with vlc player as someone found on the bug report.

Comment: After it worked with vlc, now open with cheese again, it works. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the suggestions to resolve this one.  Yes it does work in VLC but no luck in Cheese. If there is a message saying that 'There is an issue retrieving the information for this feed' or similar, then the only fix I could find was to lower the resolution to 640x320 and it worked perfectly.

Hope this helps.